# How to replace blank values with previous numbers in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

```
SS     RR
       10.4
12.6  
 
       5.6
8.7
```

I want to fill in the blank rows with preceding values.

Intended result:

```
SS     RR
       10.4
12.6   10.4
12.6   10.4      
12.6   5.6
8.7    5.6
8.7    5.6
```

I am trying to first replace the blank values with NaN and then the iteration of preceding values:

```
df[df['SS']==""] = np.NaN
df[df['RR']==""] = np.NaN

df.SS.fillna(method='ffill')
df.RR.fillna(method='ffill')
```

But for some reason it doesn't make any difference to the dataframe. What am i missing here? Thanks!

EDIT:
What if I want to `ffill` within the respective 'ID':

```
ID     SS     RR
ABC          10.4
ABC   12.6  
ABC     
LMN           5.6
LMN   8.7
```

Intended result:

```
ID     SS     RR
ABC          10.4
ABC   12.6   10.4
ABC   12.6   10.4
LMN           5.6
LMN   8.7     5.6
```

Do i use the `groupby` function and where to add it to make things work? Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **don't need `fillna`** here, you can call [`ffill()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html) directly:

```
In [1793]: df[['SS', 'RR']] = df[['SS', 'RR']].ffill()

In [1794]: df
Out[1794]: 
     SS    RR
0   NaN  10.4
1  12.6  10.4
2  12.6  10.4
3  12.6   5.6
4   8.7   5.6
```

Comment: Hey, i have edited in a slightly different problem if you can pls have a look. Thanks.

Comment: Something like this might work: `df.groupby('ID')[['SS', 'RR']].ffill()`

Answer (score 2):

You should assign it back or add `inplace`

```
df.SS.fillna(method='ffill',inplace=True)
df.RR.fillna(method='ffill',inplace=True)

#df.SS = df.SS.fillna(method='ffill')
#df.RR = df.RR.fillna(method='ffill')
```

Answer (score 1):

`fillna` does not operate inplace. You'll either need to add `inplace=True` to your calls to `fillna` as another answer has indicated.

Alternatively you can rewrite your code to overwrite your dataframe with the corrected output.

```
df = df.replace("", np.nan).ffill()
```

- `.replace("", np.nan)` will replace all blanks with `NaN` throughout your entire dataframe
- `.ffill()` is a shortcut for `.fillna(method="ffill")`

Since we're not specifying the `inplace=True` flag here, we can chain these methods together and overwrite our dataframe (or produce a new dataframe with these alterations by changing our variable name:

```
clean_df = df.replace("", np.nan).ffill()
```

Comment: Hey, i have edited in a slightly different problem if you can pls have a look. Thanks.